# 2008 toyota corolla overheating and heater not working

Tags: toyota, cooling-system, corolla, temperature

My corolla temp will gradually go up while driving and then come back down on its own while driving.  The heater is not working.  Blowing cold air.  We have replaced the water pump, thermostat, and temperature sensor plug.  Radiator is not clogged.  All hoses seem fine.  We are out of ideas.

Comment: Coolant level? Air lock?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!